# URL-rewriting Codeigniter htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

Since I changed a website to another server, I have a problem that I can't access the website on domain.com/codeigniter/ . My default controller is info/
It worked with http://www.domain.com/codeigniter/info/ and http://www.domain.com/codeigniter/info/model/

```
$route['default_controller'] = "info/";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['info/(:any)'] = "info/view/$1";
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

But on the new server it doesn't work. The problem is that it always ends in http://www.domain.com/index.php and not the index.php of the directory of the codeigniter installation..

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

there are a few things that make CodeIgniter work in secondary folder: first of all, you must change `$config['base_url'] = http://www.domain.com/codeigniter/';` in **application/config/config.php**.

Then, of course, change .htacces file to this:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # block hidden directories
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Php **mod_rewrite** module is needed.

Comment: 1 problem solved: adding a ? after index.php

Only still a problem with the index.php

Answer (score 1):

After changing the .htacces and leaving the 'base_url' empty (http://www.domain.com/codeigniter/ doesn't work).

I have the following problems:

```
http://www.domain.com/codeigniter/ --> ERROR 404 from CI
http://www.domain.com/codeigniter/info/ --> No input file specified
http://www.domain.com/codeigniter/index.php/info/ --> OK
```

EDIT: Problem solved.. I forgot a ? after the index.php in the .htaccess & I changed the default controller in routes.php to info/view/home/

It was a combination of multiple things... It is strange that it worked on the old hosting. It was obviously wrong..